# Restoring access to S3 bucket after accidentally deleting it

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I was trying some S3 bucket access control policies for IAM roles and users. Accidentally, I removed myself and all other users from the list of users who can access my own bucket. Is there anyway to restore the access to it?

I first manually deleted all access to everyone but me (owner of the bucket)
then bucket policy I applied the bucket policy as below:

```
{
"Id": "Policy1488129168784",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1488129161523",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": "*",
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::field-engineering",
"arn:aws:s3:::field-engineering/*"
],
"Condition": {
"StringNotLike": {
"aws:userid": [
"AROA-IAM_ROLE1",
"AROA-IAM_ROLE2",
"MyUserId"
]
}
}
}
]
}
```

After testing this, i thought of removing the MyUserID from the above policy and applied it to the bucket, not realizing that I will not have any access to it
Now I am stuck without any access to my bucket (not even as a root user).
Is there any way to reverse the policy?

Comment: Assume one of those roles, then replace the policy? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html

Comment: Worst case, use the Root Account to delete/modify the Bucket Policy.

Comment: I was able to delete the Bucket Policy from the Root Account and add back the group policies to gain back the access. Thank you for all your helo